# How to remove water stains from TV

Tags: appliances

Somebody tried to clean the LCD smart TV (which is not supposed to be cleaned that way) with water and now it is full of water stains. I've tried gently rubbing it with a dry cloth but they don't seem to go away. 2 months have passed but they don't seem to deteriorate at all..

Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: Can you give us more details? E.g. what is exact model of this smart TV. Perhaps you could find in users manual what is it's surface made from or what kind of detergents can be used for cleaning?

Comment: It is the LG SmartTV

Comment: Wow, there is [almost 50 models](http://www.lg.com/us/smart-tvs) of LG SmartTVs. I think if you want someone to help you, you could try little bit more and at least try to find exact model, look into users manual or something.

Comment: @running.t I don't think it matters what model it is. I am interested in removing the stains from the material of the screen. it could have been any LCD TV (Btw I don't think I have the manual any more. That's why I cannot find the exact model. I'll try to see if anything is written on the Tv and update my question. I doubt that this information will help anyone though.)

Answer (score 2):

Spray just a bit of glass-cleaner or clear rubbing alcohol on a clean, absorbent cloth and polish gently with the slightly damp cloth.

If the residue is from dissolved minerals left after the water evaporated, that should remove it. However, if damage was done to a surface coating, it will probably not help.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work as well. It made things a little better than the other proposed solution (newspaper and water) but I find it impossible to completely remove the stains (at least to an acceptable level)

Answer (score 0):

Just sprinkle some water drops on screen. Take a newspaper and start cleaning the water with it. keep rubbing the newspaper till whole water is absorbed. It will clean all the spots. It is easy and cheap way to clean all screens like TV , mobile. ;-)

Comment: Isn't this going to make more damage to the screen?

Comment: I tried it on my screen and it worked. you can try it on small portion of screen. If it works, you can do it for full screen.

Comment: That's how I clean all my LCD monitors. It works. I use soft paper towels instead of newspapers, though (cloth works, too, if it's a kind that doesn't leave fibers). The key is to keep rubbing until the surface is completely dry, otherwise you will probably have stains again.

Comment: This works on everything that is glass and works very well!! I use this all the time +1

Comment: Just tried that and it doesn't work. The stains are not removed this way :(

Comment: Well, some water is so full of mineral stuff that any trace of water after drying out leaves a trace of hard salty substance. Is that how water is in your area? Very noticeable on glass cups, if you don't wipe them completely dry. Can remove them with something like baking soda, ash or a hard sponge, but those are probably going to do more damage than good to an LCD screen. Try soaking a single stain for a while (with a really wet piece of cotton, etc.) to see if it dissolves back, then wipe it dry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Samsung LCD TV and here is how I solved it.

I used a 100 cotton piece preferably a blanket and breathed on it.

I breathed on the scratched part then immediately rubbed with the blanket.  It worked like magic.

Comment: @papakias so you're using a TV screen with water stains for year and half??

Comment: @ShadowWizard hahahah obviously not. `i will try it if it happens again though.